# How to sync music from old PC to new PC?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, music, iphone

I have a new iPhone 6 and need to get my non-purchased music from the old iPhone 4S to the new phone.

When I connect to iTunes on the new PC (with the old phone) and select `Sync Music` I get the warning asking me if I'm sure, and do I want to remove existing music etc. from this iPhone. And of course I don't because all the music I need is on that old iPhone. The old PC crashed and is no longer available. How can I transfer the songs to the new phone without having access to the old PC that the 4S used to sync with?

Answer (score 1):

I backup all media contents from my old iPhone 4 to iCloud, and then login the same account on the new iPhone 6, and then sync all media to the new phone, quite convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You cant because itunes relies on the physical media to be in the itunes media folder on the computer.

Do you still physically have the old computer? A solution would be to remove the old Hard Drive from your computer (which has all the data stored on it) and purchase a usb to 3.5" Hard drive adapter. This means you will be able to transfer your old itunes library into your new one and then successfully sync the music to your iphone.

Answer (score 0):

You can only sync your iPhone with 1 iTunes Library at a time. If your old PC has crashed and the iTunes Library is no longer accessible you will have to sync your phone with your new PC.

Syncing your iPhone on your new computer will wipe your phone but you can always re-download any purchased music through iTunes and put it back on your phone. Any music you burned will have to be reburned and copied onto your new computer.

Comment: So if I understand correctly...I can go ahead and sync with the new pc and it will wipe the phone but will transfer any existing non purchased music to the new itunes. Then I will at least have the music from the old phone in the new itunes. From there I can sync the new phone and should get the music that was on the old phone to sync to the new phone...?

Comment: No, iTunes won't take any music from your phone to your PC. Whether it is purchased or not. You need to use something other than iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an application like [SharePod](http://www.getsharepod.com) to extract the music from your iPhone. It is available for Windows and Macs. It transfers 50 tracks for free but then needs to be registered to do more.

I've used [iFunBox](http://i-funbox.com) in the past, which is completely free, but I just tried it there and it can't see the contents of my Music folder. I'm sure I used it successfully recently. Your mileage may vary though so you might want to try that. You may find your music under "Raw File System" in "iTunes_Control/Music/"

There are [a selection of alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/sharepod/) if you have no luck with these two.